# Change from LineString to MultiLineString when saving layer edits in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, linestring, geometry-data-type

In QGIS, when a user creates a new single part line in an open editing session for a “Multi-Line” SpatiaLite dataset, the QGIS data type is initially a “LineString”.  But, when the user commits the new record to the Multi-Line QGIS data set by pressing the “Save Layer Edits” button, QGIS changes the parsed data type from “LineString” to “MultiLineString”.  A similar change from “LineString” to “MultiLineString” occurs when committing a new single part line record to an ESRI Shapefile of type “PolyLine”.

**Is the change from “LineString” to “MultiLineString” controlled by QGIS (e.g. try saving as “LineString”, except save as “MultiLineString”), or, is it controlled by relevant data provider?**  If it is controlled by QGIS, does that imply it will be default logic for any line or multiline dataset?

Comment: When I am opening old shapefiles that were linestring, QGIS 3.10.3 opens them as Line (MultiLineStringZM).  It appears like that is the new way.  Even if I export the layer as Linestring it opens it as MultiLineString.  I cannot find any other options.